# Authorize requests for multiple roles for different URLs

Tags: spring, groovy, spring-security

I'm trying to implement different roles in my application and I cannot achieve to include/exclude URLs for different roles.

For example, I want that users with role `ROLE_USER` and anonymous users can access to the following endpoints:

```java
 String[] publiclyAccessibleUris = new String[]{ "/home", "/user", "/profile/*", "location/**", "/products/*" };
```

And I want that users with role `ROLE_DENIED` can only access to the following endpoints:

```java
 String[] publiclyAccessibleUrisForDenied = new String[]{ "/home", "/profile/*" };
```

Here is my code:

```java
 http
     .sessionManagement()
         .sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS)
         .and()
     .anonymous()
         .and()
     .authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers(publiclyAccessibleUris).hasRole("USER")
         .anyRequest().permitAll()
         .antMatchers(publiclyAccessibleUrisForDenied).hasRole("DENIED")
         .anyRequest().permitAll()
         .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("DENIED")
         .anyRequest().denyAll();
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally i solved like the following way in order to allow all urls for all users with anon o ROLE_USER, and for ROLE_SUSPENDED i set wich one i want to.

```
    http
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS)
    .and()
            .anonymous()
    .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(publiclyAccessibleUris).permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(publiclyAccessibleUrisForDenied).access("hasRole('ROLE_DENIED') or hasAuthority('DENIED') OR hasRole('ROLE_USER') or hasAuthority('USER')")
                    .anyRequest().access("hasRole('ROLE_USER') or hasAuthority('USER')");
```